# javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor : compiling generated code

Tags: java, code-generation, javac, annotation-processing

When generating java code with [javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html)

```
(...)
FileObject file=filer.createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,"xx","Hello.java");
PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(file.openWriter());
writer.println("package xx;\npublic class Hello { }");
writer.close();
(...)
```

should I run javac a second time to compile the generated code or is there a hack to tell javac to compile the new classes on the fly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `createSourceFile` method then your new sources should get compiled for you. Your "create" method should look like the following:

```
FileObject file = filer.createSourceFile("xx.Hello");
```

If some existing element "caused" this to get generated, you should add it to the `createSourceFile` call as an `originatingElement`.

Comment: hum, no the class Hello is not compiled unless I declare it as a field in a `javac file`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were also using ``createResource`` -- you'll want to use ``createSourceFile`` here in addition to specifying the ``SOURCE_OUTPUT`` location.

Comment: And...I was operating from memory...answer updated to a tested example.